# Facebook Graph api - post to friends timeline issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api

when I tried to post to my friends timeline using facebook graph api, I got

{"error":{"message":"(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Enabling something while creating access_token will resolve this problem ?

If so what should I enable.

Thanks,

Padmaprasad G

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been removed the 6th February : http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Look here how to do it [Facebook App: Will fb.api method post on friend's wall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415701/facebook-app-will-fb-api-method-post-on-friends-wall)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this was announced few months back and took effect on Feb 6th - http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes

```
Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API
We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post.
```

The workaround is to use the Feed Dialog which allows users to post the same content, but choose the user they want to post it to.