# How do you post to a friend's wall using the C# Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

So I tried to post on my friends wall using the following code:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "Google is your friend";
parameters.link = "http://gidf.de/";
parameters.Name = "Test";
parameters.from = new { id = "100000", name = "me" };
parameters.to = new { id = "1000001", name = "friend" };
dynamic result = fb.Post("1000001/feed", parameters);
```

However, I get told that my application does not support this. I did some googling work, and read that `[USER_ID]/feed` is deprecated and that I have to invoke the feed dialog to ask the user to publish it. How would I go on doing this with the C# SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of February 6, 2013, you can't post to Friends Timeline on behalf of the user.
Read Here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Client-Side you can use the FB.ui method to pop up the feed dialog.
Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15426243/1405120

Server-Side, you can use the URL Redirection.
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=458358780877780
  &link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/
  &redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/`

Read more about Feed dialog here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/